# Creating all combinations from a variable-sized list

Tags: python

Given a string such as "xyz", I would like to generate all dictionaries of the form:

```
{"x": vx, "y": vy, "z": vz}
```

where `vx`, `vy`, `vz` are integers between 1 and 5.

So in the above case, there are 125 such dictionaries. But the string can have variable length.

What is a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: How can be `vx` an integer between 1 and 5 , I don't completly understand your question!

Comment: He wants all possible dictionaries resulting from choosing each of `vx`, `vy`, and `vz` from set {1,2,3,4,5}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm positive this is a duplicate but I can't find a good one right now, so I'll answer and make it community wiki.  Using `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> s = "xyz"
>>> [dict(zip(s,v)) for v in product(range(1,6),repeat=len(s))]
[{'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 2}, {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}, {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 4}, {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 4}, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}, {'y': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'y': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}, {'y': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 4}, {'y': 3, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 2}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 4}, {'y': 4, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}, {'y': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'y': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 2}, {'y': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 4}, {'y': 5, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}, {'y': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 2}, {'y': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 3}, {'y': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}, {'y': 1, 'x': 2, 'z': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}, {'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 5}, {'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 1}, {'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 3}, {'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}, {'y': 3, 'x': 2, 'z': 5}, {'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 2}, {'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 3}, {'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}, {'y': 4, 'x': 2, 'z': 5}, {'y': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 1}, {'y': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 2}, {'y': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 4}, {'y': 5, 'x': 2, 'z': 5}, {'y': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 2}, {'y': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 3}, {'y': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, {'y': 1, 'x': 3, 'z': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, {'y': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 5}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3, 'z': 1}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3, 'z': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3, 'z': 3}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, {'y': 3, 'x': 3, 'z': 5}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 2}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 3}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, {'y': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 5}, {'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'z': 1}, {'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'z': 2}, {'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'z': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, {'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'z': 5}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 2}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 3}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 4}, {'y': 1, 'x': 4, 'z': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 4, 'z': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 4, 'z': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 4, 'z': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 4, 'z': 4}, {'y': 2, 'x': 4, 'z': 5}, {'y': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 1}, {'y': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 3}, {'y': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 4}, {'y': 3, 'x': 4, 'z': 5}, {'y': 4, 'x': 4, 'z': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 4, 'z': 2}, {'y': 4, 'x': 4, 'z': 3}, {'y': 4, 'x': 4, 'z': 4}, {'y': 4, 'x': 4, 'z': 5}, {'y': 5, 'x': 4, 'z': 1}, {'y': 5, 'x': 4, 'z': 2}, {'y': 5, 'x': 4, 'z': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 4, 'z': 4}, {'y': 5, 'x': 4, 'z': 5}, {'y': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 1}, {'y': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 2}, {'y': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}, {'y': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 4}, {'y': 1, 'x': 5, 'z': 5}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 1}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 2}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 4}, {'y': 2, 'x': 5, 'z': 5}, {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 1}, {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 2}, {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}, {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 4}, {'y': 3, 'x': 5, 'z': 5}, {'y': 4, 'x': 5, 'z': 1}, {'y': 4, 'x': 5, 'z': 2}, {'y': 4, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}, {'y': 4, 'x': 5, 'z': 4}, {'y': 4, 'x': 5, 'z': 5}, {'y': 5, 'x': 5, 'z': 1}, {'y': 5, 'x': 5, 'z': 2}, {'y': 5, 'x': 5, 'z': 3}, {'y': 5, 'x': 5, 'z': 4}, {'y': 5, 'x': 5, 'z': 5}]
>>> len(_)
125
```

Note that we haven't hardcoded the length of the string.

Comment: Deleted my (near) duplicate answer; I forgot about the `repeat` argument to `product`.

Comment: Thanks! I have to study this itertools library more in depth.